# Kinect CLNU driver data to EmguCV C# IImage format

Tags: emgucv, kinect

I want to interface with kinect using emguCV C#.
I am using the CLNU drivers.

I am unable to convert the CLNUDevice.getCameraColorFrameRGB32() output IntPtr to any usable format. I tried new Image(width= 480, hieght=640, stride = 480 * 3, IntPtr)

Any help is appreciated. I do believe it is the c# version of the code given here. http://codelaboratories.com/forums/viewthread/518/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
IntPtr rgb32 = CLNUIDevice.getCameraColorFrameRGB32();
MIplImage rgb32Image = new MIplImage();
rgb32Image = (MIplImage)Marshal.PtrToStructure(rgb32, typeof(MIplImage));
```

Where, of course, rgb32Image is what's needed. I'm not immediately sure about how to use the Image<> class with this, though I'm sure some conversion exists between MIplImage and Image<>.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well I realized that the library dll contains some function that converts the data into bitmap. so now i have a emgucv Image<>.
so basically, you need to just add this in the NUIImage.cs, wherever u need.

return new Image(new System.Drawing.Bitmap(640, 480, 640 * 4, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, depthImage.ImageData));

You can use the same code to get a bitmap as well.
This is a simple, trivial hack. I hope some1 can explain wat is going on.
It is fast though.

Comment: Hi Samarth, what function did you use to get the EmguCV Image<> object?

Comment: Well, the CLNU driver kit has a NUIImage.cs. I used the imageData IntPtr to convert to bitmap and then to Image<>.